# Is there a way to schedule aptd to check for updates only at certain times?

Tags: apt, cron

On Ubuntu 12.04 I've noticed that aptd sometimes uses 100% of a CPU and tends to slow down my whole laptop. I wasn't installing any packages so I'm assuming that this is the automatic update check.

Is there a way to schedule aptd to only check for updates at certain times?

I checked the crontab for root but down't see anything in there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use **Gnome Schedule** to set any activity to be executed at the time you want.

It is in the official repo:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule

or check it in the USC.

Then launch it and create new task that launches recurrently.

You can add a description and 'update-manager' as command, finally in advanced time and date you can set when precisely start your task.

Hope it can be helpful for other tasks too.

Obviously you had to set Update Manager to never check for updates from its own settings menu or it will not stop to pop up.